# Microsoft Project - display "plan schedule" vs "actual schedule"

Tags: ms-project, tools

I work on a project with many changes. To get data about how these changes affect my project, I want to show my boss about my plan gantt & actual gantt on the same diagram. Could I do this with Microsoft Project? if yes, please show me how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Especially with a complex project trying to have two Gantt charts essentially overlapping is going to get messy and difficult to interpret. A better bet may be to create a table of four columns:

- First column is the milestone
- Second column is baseline completion date
- Third column is predicted ("actual") completion date
- Fourth column is variance

Answer (score 4):

Set your view to tracking Gantt.  After you baseline your schedule, there will be two bars on each package.  One shows your baseline, the other shows your actual.  If you have your packages predecessor and successor logic captured well, the actual gantt will show your finish variances throughout the entire project, including your critical path.